# How to embed or convert PDF to support reading on mobile browser with offline support?

Tags: html, pdf, web-applications, mobile

Before you downvote please read the full post. It is a legit question, for witch I have googled and found some answer but all come short therefore I come to the community and ask for advice.

The requirement asks for the ability to read catalogs that are in pdf format inside a **mobile** browser. There is also the need to read the files offline, so this kills a few options like google pdf viewer.

So faces with this requirement I have not found an easy way to embed a pdf file, therefore conversion to HTML5 or Images is the route that I am thinking on going.

In terms of HTML5 conversion I have found Flexpaper, crocodoc, Prizm, serverPDF and others, but almost all require the user to be online to read the files. Is there a client side only way to read and display PDF files? Or an intermediate browser/js friendly format?

Comment: Chances are that if you find an offline format (ie. html5 with base64 encoded ressources for example) the result will be significantly bigger than the original pdf.

Comment: I have tried to put it in images and the file size is smaller, you lose the ability to select text, but for this example it is not necessary, it's the images that I am interested in.

Comment: I was talking about embedded ressources (fonts+images) to allow text selection/search.Indeed using images only you may end up with smaller file sizes than the original pdf.You may want to have a look at cbz/cbr formats if images is all you need

Answer (score 1):

if you optimize this project, maybe it will work

[js and html pdf viewer](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/)